# How to generate values in dataset

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, dataset

I have the dataset in a text file in below format:

```
user ID   Song ID   Rating
0         7171      5
0         8637      4
0         21966     4
0         35821     5
```

(It has no dashes between just a TAB space between them)

I have about 1 million records like this. I need  to generate a fourth record that has genre ID. This genre ID I have it in another text file like in below format:

```
Song ID   Album ID   Artist ID  Genre ID
4         243        2282       0
5         7783       3832       0
6         11704      1655       106
7         10126      6328       114
8         10672      4121       0
```

How to generate the "genre ID" for the corresponding "song ID" in the dataset.
Can you please suggest an easiest way to generate the fourth column.

Comment: Do you wanna create a new one or based on the songID you wanna create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ Anders Finn : He's using MySQL, It doesn't support `SELECT ....INTO`(Oracle)

```
 INSERT INTO newTable
 SELECT tb1.userID, tb1.SongID, tb1.Rating, tb2.GenreID
 FROM tab1
 LEFT JOIN tab2
 ON tab1.SongID = tab2.SongID
```

I would've added it as a comment, but I still can't.

Comment: Hi praveen..is this the simplest way.. i have about 717 million records....is ter any other solution using hadoop or smethg?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with all four columns:

```
CREATE TABLE newTable
( 
  userid int,
  SongID int,
  Rating int,
  GenreID int
)
```

The populate it:

```
SELECT tb1.userID, tb1.SongID, tb1.Rating, tb2.GenreID
INTO newTable
FROM tab1
LEFT JOIN tab2
ON tab1.SongID = tab2.SongID
```

Below
it's said that the syntax doesnt apply for mySQL and only for Oracle. the syntax fra mysql are described here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

In this case the result would be:

```
INSERT INTO newTable (userID, SongID, Rating, GenreID)
SELECT tb1.userID, tb1.SongID, tb1.Rating, tb2.GenreID
FROM tab1
LEFT JOIN tab2
ON tab1.SongID = tab2.SongID
```

If there is many millions records it would be an idea to create an index on SONGID on tab1 and tab2.

Comment: ..is this the simplest way.. i have about 717 million records....is ter any other solution using hadoop or smethg?